# Create fake JNIEnv and jobject for JNI function call from C program

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call function from the Android JNI library, using libhybris.
Code based on this repository https://github.com/unverbraucht/libhybris-sample

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <hybris/common/binding.h>
#include "jni.h"
#include <stdio.h>

HYBRIS_LIBRARY_INITIALIZE(hellojni, "./libhello-jni.so")

int main (void)
{
    static jstring (*f)(JNIEnv*, jobject) FP_ATTRIB = NULL;
    HYBRIS_DLSYSM(hellojni, &f, "Java_com_kevinread_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI");

    //f(env, obj); Where to get or how to create dummy JNIEnv and jobject for this function?
}
```

Now I'm stuck on the function call stage, cause don't have JNIEnv and jobject variables.

Comment: JNI provides for embedding a JVM in a C program.  That's how you would obtain a `JNIEnv` in which to run Java code.  You would get an appropriate `jobject` by performing an appropriate sequence of calls to JNI functions.  The specific sequence depends on what kind of object you need and how you need to prepare it.

Comment: If you are trying to invoke a static (native) method then presumably the `jobject` needed is a `jclass` representing the class to which the method belongs, as loaded into the JVM in which it is to run.  In this case, you would probably need to use [`FindClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#FindClass) to get that class loaded into the VM.  Of course, that means that the class needs to be available in the Java classpath configured for the VM.

Comment: You can get the JVM from `GetJavaJVM()`, and you can get a `JNIEnv*` via `AttachCurrentThread()`.